# python api - shopify.Asset 404 Error

Tags: python, shopify

I am trying to create an asset using the shopify python library but I'm getting a ResourceNotFound exception. The following is a snippet of my code.

```
asset = shopify.Asset(dict(key=self.key, theme_id=theme_id))
asset.attach(image.read())
asset.save()
```

Here's the stacktrace of the exception

```
Traceback:
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  105.                         response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/pages/middleware.py" in process_view
  45.             return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/workspace/sg/djangoproject/shopify_app/decorators.py" in wrapper
  10.         return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/workspace/sg/djangoproject/shopify_galleries/views.py" in dispatch
  81.         return super(UploadImageView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/src/django/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  138.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/workspace/sg/djangoproject/shopify_galleries/views.py" in form_valid
  96.             image.store_image(image_field)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/workspace/sg/djangoproject/shopify_galleries/models.py" in store_image
  62.             asset.save()
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py" in save
  151.         return super(ShopifyResource, self).save()
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py" in save
  775.                         data=self.to_xml())
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py" in put
  351.         return self._open('PUT', path, headers=headers, data=data)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shopify/base.py" in _open
  18.             self.response = super(ShopifyConnection, self)._open(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py" in _open
  287.                 http_response = self._handle_error(err)
File "/home/rodxavierbondoc/.virtualenvs/shopify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyactiveresource/connection.py" in _handle_error
  407.             raise ResourceNotFound(err)

Exception Type: ResourceNotFound at /galleries/upload/
Exception Value: Not Found: https://sawayn-and-sons9677.myshopify.com/admin/themes/3422503/assets.xml
```

any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post the full traceback of the ResourceNotFound error.

Comment: Edited the question and included the exception traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found your request in our logs, and noticed that the key you are using is "14e2ccbe-601e-4bd8-bb61-726c221b53cf-6..png".

Assets need to be in a suitable directory.

- Liquid templates => "templates/"
- Liquid layouts => "layout/"
- Liquid snippets => "snippets/"
- Theme settings => "config/"
- General assets => "assets/"
- etc

In your case you probably want `key = "assets/14e2ccbe-601e-4bd8-bb61-726c221b53cf-6.png"`

Sorry about the unhelpfulness of the error message.  The 404 was referring to the key's directory not being found.